# What do the different colours and markers mean on the experience bar?

Tags: the-secret-world

What do the different colours and markers mean on the experience bar?

It seems to be split into *three* sections with two markers and the both the bar and the markers can be orange or blue, what does this mean?

Comment: +1, I know it has something to do with AP and SP Earned/Coming soon, but I can't make heads or tails of exactly how the bar works. I thought I knew until I tried to answer this.

Comment: I thought the current segment was orange if you'd be awarded AP, and blue if you'd get an additional SP (you *always* get an AP) but I'm actually not sure.

Comment: I was under the impression that the last third would be blue all but I have an instance where the first third is blue at the moment... so unsure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually confusing but I did a little googling and found [this dev blog](http://thesecretworld.com/news/blog_lead_designer_martin_bruusgaard_explains_character_development) from the lead designer. I have added emphasis to the key parts of the paragraph.

> In order to explain the progression we need to start talking about xp. **At the bottom of the screen is the xp bar, and when the player has filled up 1/3 of it they will be given an ability point. Filling out the whole bar gives a skill point.** A player gets xp from many different sources: Killing monsters, PvP, missions and crafting. **The amount of xp needed to get an ability point or a skill point is static**.

So it looks like everyone was on the right-ish track but I think we were reading too much into the bar.

EDIT: A bit more info from playing more tonight. The blue area will fill up each third of the XP bar as your progress. When you completely fill the bar you will get an AP point and the redish tint will go over that section of the bar. When you fill all three bars, that is when you get an SP.

Comment: @dujore Could you explain what you are seeing a bit more? I went up two SPs and 5 APs last night and saw the above functionality working as described.

Comment: I sometimes see the first or second thirds of the bar as blue, too, that's the only thing that really is confusing me.  I had thought it worked like that dev said...but the colors are confusing.

Comment: @dujore The bar starts blank. As you gain XP the blue bar will move upward from left to right. When you read the 1/3rd mark and the 2/3rd mark it will cover that section with a red tint marking that you have achieved that AP for that second of the bar. When you fill up the last third of the bar you get both an AP and a SP and the bar resets to empty again. The part that can cause a bit of confusion is that the blue bar has a tick at the end of it making it look like the separation between the Red and Blue is important. Its not. It is just how far back you got your last AP.

Comment: @james ty i guess that makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

Best way I can explain the experience bar is this way.

You have an experience bar at the bottom of the screen divided into 3. Every time 1/3 of the bar gets filled you get 1 AP which is used to buy your abilities. Every time you complete 100% of the experience bar you get 1 SP which is used to upgrade your weapons and armor. When you complete a full 100% experience bar you will get 3 AP and 1 SP.

The experience bar is a total of 120,000 experience which equals 1 SP, thus 1 AP is 40,000 experience.

Experience can be earned from killing monsters, doing quest, and pvp.